# Wireless access point - high performance

Tags: networking, wifi

Can anyone recommend a wireless access point solution that will handle 25-50 users streaming video?  I am very familiar with consumer grade stuff and don't want to assume anything I can buy at Frys will handle this kind of load. Also do you think gigabit network will suffice back to the router or do I need fiber?  This is for a school, so cost is a large factor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping questions/product recommendations aren't allowed.  They quickly get outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aruba Networks](http://www.arubanetworks.com/) will do exactly what you want. A colleague has deployed it in sports arenas, college campuses, and even outside for small communities. It is rock solid and highly adaptable.

[Ruckus Wireless](http://www.ruckuswireless.com/) is another good system. It is cheaper than Aruba, but still offers good quality gear and technology. I have used this personally and it is easy to setup and maintain.

Comment: +1.  To add to this - a solution like this is what you want; a single high-performance access point is not.  This is because a single AP's bandwidth is shared by all of the connected clients; you may be able to get that many clients to associate, but if they're all using it at the same time then traffic contention would be fierce.

Comment: Both the Aruba and Ruckus gear will do a "mesh" network with the access points.

Comment: Thanks for the traffic contention tip.  The guys at Aruba concurred. Aruba has some great user management firms/software too.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I would add that "shared bandwidth" is the least of your worries. That is the optimal case assuming optimal carrier utilization from multiple agents that have no way to cooperate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11_RTS/CTS for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Aruba and Ruckus are indeed top-of-the-class enterprise level solutions. BUT, for a fraction of the cost you could set up almost the exact same thing using Ubiquiti equipment, from the [UniFi](http://www.ubnt.com/unifi#UnifiHardware) product range. The quality is great, the interface clean and informative and they even have some kind of API in development (it is in Alpha as of this writing). You do need a dedicated machine to run the UniFi Controller app (actually it does not NEED to be dedicated, just always on), but I have used net-tops with celeron processors for some clients of mine, and they work like a charm.